# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mycompany_live.debit_bankdata' doesn't exist

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9.4.0 with Patch SUPEE-11086 and PHP 5.6. I get this error logged into my console after checkout:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:222:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mycompany_live.magedebit_bankdata' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `magedebit_bankdata`.`bank_name` FROM `magedebit_bankdata` WHERE (swift_code='5498494') LIMIT$
#1 /home/mycompany/live/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mycompany/live/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/mycompany/live/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `magedeb...', Array)
#4 /home/mycompany/live/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `magedeb...', Array)
#5 /home/mycompany/live/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/mycompany/live/app/code/community/Itabs/Debit/Model/Resource/Bankdata.php(83): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home/mycompany/live/app/code/community/Itabs/Debit/Model/Bankdata.php(65): Itabs_Debit_Model_Resource_Bankdata->loadByIdentifier('swift', '5498494', NULL)
#8 /home/mycompany/live/app/code/community/Itabs/Debit/Helper/Data.php(81): Itabs_Debit_Model_Bankdata->loadByIdentifier('swift', '5498494', NULL)
#9 /home/mycompany/live/app/code/community/Itabs/Debit/controllers/AjaxController.php(42): Itabs_Debit_Helper_Data->getBankByIdentifier('swift', '5498494')
#10 /home/mycompany/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Itabs_Debit_AjaxController->checkblzAction()
#11 /home/mycompany/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('checkblz')
#12 /home/mycompany/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/mycompany/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home/mycompany/live/app/Mage.php(690): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/mycompany/live/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}";s:3:"url";s:21:"/debit/ajax/checkblz/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

The checkout works and the correct bank data is saved, so why do I get this message?

Comment: you have third party extension install ?

Comment: Yes I do have third party extension installed, e.g. `Itabs/Debit` as you can see in the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually rewind `core_resource` 
Take the following steps to resolve the issue.

- Open the database table ‘**core_resource**’
- Browse the table and find: **debit_resource** // your extension setup
- Remove this entry (only one)
- Refresh the cache
- The error should be gone!

Comment: The error is gone, thx bro!